# Hosts file spoofing detection/protection

Tags: security

I have an application that calls an web api to validate its license, the license is signed by private key and validated by public key on the client machine. Lets say that some 'attacker' found a workaround and have setup a custom http server and have modified hosts file to redirect my application to that server, he is also able to modify the public key by decompiling and altering my application code, effectively he is able to issue his own application licenses.

Now my question is assuming that I will be able to protect the applications public key from tampering what would be a correct way to verify that hosts file is not compromised and application is actually calling my own http server.

Some potential solutions I can think of is to call my api with its http server static IP and include the host in the headers, still I would assume it would be possible to alter the request by other means like some kind of proxy?

Another thought is to send an small payload to my api and sign it, then on client side the signature could be verified, since the 'attacker' does not possesses the private key he would not be able to produce correct payload. Of course this would only work if my application public key cant be compromised.

Any ideas comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend looking up a software activation scheme that is already done and look at the features published for it and.   Consider the accuracy of this feature list verses the effort to circumvent them.   Might help to look at how others have solved the same problem.